# Load GeoJson file for Leaflet choropleth

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a GeoJson file that I am trying to load to logic.js for the Leaflet. I console.logged the response and it fetches the data, however, when I try to apply the data onto the map, it gives me the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.` 
My GeoJSON data looks like this:

```
  "type": "WineCollection",
  "wines": [
    {
      "type": "wine",
      "properties": {
        "country": "Albania",
        "points": 88.0,
        "price": 20.0
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          19.9999619,
          41.000028
        ]
      }
    },
```

Here is my code:

```
  center: [40.7128, -74.0059],
  zoom: 2.5
});

// Adding tile layer
L.tileLayer("https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}", {
  attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href=\"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href=\"https://www.mapbox.com/\">Mapbox</a>",
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: "mapbox.streets",
  accessToken: API_KEY
}).addTo(myMap);

d3.json("static/js/wine.json").then(function(data) {
  L.geoJson(data).addTo(myMap);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data sample is not compliant with [GeoJSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946).

You can have an object of type "FeatureCollection", having an array of "features", which are objects of type "Feature" (and having "properties" and a "geometry" like in your data sample).

Unfortunately you cannot customise those types.

There are several GeoJSON linting tool available that can help you quickly spot non compliant data, e.g. http://geojsonlint.com/