# Add choropleth layer to Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, choropleth

Trying to construct a Leaflet map. The goal is to place average points on the map for each country, using Choropleth. BindpopUp works. But for some reason, it doesn't show the borders of the countries like it was intended to but only the simple markers. Which is what I do not want.

```
var myMap = L.map("map", {
  center: [40.7128, -74.0059],
  zoom: 2.5
});

// Adding tile layer
L.tileLayer(
  "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}",
  {
    attribution:
      'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: "mapbox.streets",
    accessToken: API_KEY
  }
).addTo(myMap);

var geojson;

// Grab the data with d3
d3.json("static/js/wine.json").then(function(data) {
  // This should place borders for the countries
   L.geoJson(data).addTo(myMap);
  // Create a new choropleth layer
  geojson = L.choropleth(data, {
    // Define what  property in the features to use
    valueProperty: "points",

    // Set color scale
    scale: ["#ffffb2", "#b10026"],

    // Number of breaks in step range
    steps: 10,

    // q for quartile, e for equidistant, k for k-means
    mode: "q",
    style: {
      // Border color
      color: "#fff",
      weight: 1,
      fillOpacity: 0.8
    },

    // Binding a pop-up to each layer
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(
        feature.properties.country +
          ", " +
          feature.properties.points+
          "<br>Median Price per bottle of wine:<br>" +
          "$" +
          feature.properties.price
      );
    }
  }).addTo(myMap);

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load GeoJson file for Leaflet choropleth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739661/load-geojson-file-for-leaflet-choropleth)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I have my data displayed on the map just not the way I want it. It shows markers and I need colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample data from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739661/load-geojson-file-for-leaflet-choropleth), you simply need to modify your GeoJSON data to specify "Polygon" type geometries (with array of coordinates), instead of your current "Point" type geometries (which are rendered by default by Leaflet as simple Markers).

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.